# Getting error in image uploading

Tags: php, android

I am developing an app in which it is asking user to upload profile pic,when user click on submit button the profile pic will store in database.But when users tried to upload their profile pic it is giving error.

Here is my android code:

```
      class ContentDATA extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Upload.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting song json and parsing
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        java.util.List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p_category", type[ch2]));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p_name",p_name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p_content", p_content));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p_price",price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("prd_pic",profice_pic));


        // getting JSON string from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(DATA_URL, "POST",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Single Track JSON: ", json);

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            if (jObj != null) {
                DATA_F = jObj.getString("cdata");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And this is my php code:

```
<?php
    require 'db_connect.php';
     header('Content-Type: image/jpg; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
      header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

    $p_category=$_REQUEST['p_category'];
    $p_name=$_REQUEST['p_name'];
    $p_content=$_REQUEST['p_content'];
    $p_price=$_REQUEST['p_price'];


$flag["cdata"]="fail";

$flag['code']=0;

if($r=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `v_upload`(`p_category`, `p_name`, `p_content`, `p_price`) VALUES ('$p_category','$p_name','$p_content','$p_price')",$con))
    {
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
$binary=base64_decode($_REQUEST['prd_pic']);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8'); 
$file = fopen('Images/Product/'.$id.'.jpg', 'wb');
// Create File
fwrite($file,$binary);
fclose($file);
$filename2='Images/Product/'.$id.'.jpg';
if(file_exists($filename2))
{
$flag["cdata"]="Sucess";
$flag['code']=1;
}
else
{
$flag["cdata"]="fail";
$flag['code']=0;
}
}
echo json_encode($flag);
mysql_close($con);

   ?>
```

Error: near

```
    public void run() {
                if (DATA_F.equals("Sucess")) {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(Upload.this, "Succes",
                            "Upload SucessFully", true);
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference

Comment: when you talk about error then also post error logs of that error.

Comment: please share the error